# Chrome: NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID for self signed certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I have a self signed certificate that doesn't expire for a year, but Chrome is complaining with:

Your connection is not private
NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Why is this happening if the certificate itself is still valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After closer inspection, I can see that the Root certificate authority that I generated the certificate with has expired, which of course makes and certificates it's based on expire as well.

So in short, you need to regenerate your Root certificate if you're doing this on a dev machine!